# надо вывести список заказов на каждом сотруднике SQL

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы:
1)**Сотрудники**: КодСотрудника, ФИОсотрудника, ПочтаСотрудника.
2)**Заказы**: КодЗаказа,Дата заказа, КодСотрудника( курирующий этот заказ)
Необходимо вывести таблицу: КодСотрудника, ФИОсотрудника, количество заказов(которое он курирует), список заказов (через запятую).
я понимаю как это все вывести отдельно, но никак не могу сделать за один запрос, Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

По идее этот запрос должен вывести нужную таблицу, если я нигде не накосячил:

```
SELECT
    E.КодСотрудника,
    E.ФИОсотрудника,
    COUNT(O.КодЗаказа) AS Количество_заказов,
    GROUP_CONCAT(O.КодЗаказа ORDER BY O.КодЗаказа SEPARATOR ', ') AS Список_заказов
FROM
    Сотрудники AS E
    LEFT JOIN Заказы AS O ON E.КодСотрудника = O.КодСотрудника
GROUP BY
    E.КодСотрудника, E.ФИОсотрудника;
```

Если кратко, то тот запрос объединяет таблицы Сотрудники и Заказы по полю КодСотрудника с помощью JOIN. Затем с помощью COUNT подсчитывается количество заказов для каждого сотрудника. GROUP_CONCAT используется для составления списка заказов через запятую. Результат группируется по коду сотрудника и ФИО сотрудника.